# GameObject initialization order

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop my unity skills while working on some project. Basically I need a dynamic scroll view that will be populate with prefabs at runtime. Here is my object hierarchy:
[image]

`27_MoreApps` is the "holder" element that has Scroll View as it subelement. `27_MoreApps` has a script attached(subclass of `MonoBehaviour`) that uses `Start` method to populate `Content` object with prefabs. For this reason the script that is attached to `27_MoreApps` has reference to `Content`(set via scene editor). So, my question is - is it possible that `Start` method would be called before `Content` is initialized and cause `NPE` ?

Comment: What does NPE mean?

Comment: You can try to set the [script execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html)

Comment: @Iggy `NullReferenceException` , I came from Java world where it is called `NullPointerException` == >  `NPE`

Comment: Define `is initialized` .. as far as I can see it already exists in your scene so the `GameObject` will already exists before any `Start` is called => no .. it is however deactivated so this might cause some troubles with initialization yes .. do you have an actual error message and code to share or is this just theoretical? -> Just try

Comment: @derHugo as I mentioned - I'm really new to unity and only learning things! So, as far I understood from your comment - everything that defined in the scene already exists before `Start` is called ? Did I got your point correctly ?

Comment: Yes the references in the Scene and the Inspectors of the scene objects are all serialized (stored in the scene asset) and all deserialized (loaded from the asset) before the first `Awake` call is made (`Start` is not called until all `Awake` and `OnEnable` are done for the entire scene) .. so the only possible trouble maker is your object being inactive and e.g. invisible for `Find` etc .. (but you should avoid these anyway ;) )

Comment: @derHugo regarding second part of your comment. Everything works fine, I did a lot of tries and have no problems ! So, the question is more theoretical, for future